# Transform array to string using jq

Tags: arrays, json, string, bash, jq

I have a json with a reasons array in the format `[]` or `["a","b","c"]`. Basically i want to replace
`drop_reasons=["a","b","c"]` in json to `drop_reasons="a,b,c"` . I know we can use `join(",")` for this with jq .However , don't know how to modify it in the json .

I have tried this -  `cat test.json | jq ' .drop_reasons = .drop_reasons | join(",") ' | sponge test.json`
, but doesn't see, to work , it tries to join the entire json rather than just drop_reasons. How do i tackle it ? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Sample json is :

```
{"id":11828997,"user":"8ddbceef-c374-44be-82f6-996b9d3f9cbd","timestamp":"2020-08-12T05:50:00+05:30","claim_timestamp":"2020-08-12T20:30:58+05:30","unique_key":"d56af2a7-10b8-4a98-b12c-a8aeab9fc56e","platform":"android","location_type":"indoor","activity_type":"unknown","activity_confidence":0,"total_day_steps":151744,"gf_total_steps":0,"step_count":122,"session_id":"1792b79c-1490-4b13-83e2-3c50ebce28f4","label":"indoor","is_claimed":false,"is_dropped":false,"drop_reasons":[],"is_valid":false,"invalid_reason":["steps>allowed_freq"],"conversion":null,"createdAt":"2020-08-12T20:30:58.385285+05:30","updatedAt":"2020-08-12T20:30:58.385285+05:30","location_uuid":null,"location_latitude":28.6673,"location_longitude":77.3915,"location_accuracy":1000,"location_speed":0,"location_timestamp":"2020-08-12T05:46:40+05:30","location_altitude":0,"location_ios_distance_filler":null,"location_ios_desired_accuracy":null,"location_distance_filter":0,"location_desired_accuracy":0,"location_course":0,"location_floor":null,"meta_data_geo_string":"28.6672867,77.3914746","meta_data_timezone":"Asia/Kolkata","meta_data_device_model":"Redmi Note 8 Pro","meta_data_device_brand":"redmi","meta_data_device_manufacturer":"xiaomi","meta_data_app_version":"0.9.31","meta_data_bundle_id":"com.pepkit.ssg","meta_data_build_no":"213","meta_data_plan_id":"a562ad72-54a9-4aea-941c-7f075e2a8b18"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a pared-down sample JSON object with just the relevant key:

```sh
$ cat test.json
{
    "drop_reasons": ["a","b","c"]
}
$ jq '.drop_reasons |= join(",")' test.json
{
  "drop_reasons": "a,b,c"
}
```

Your sample with an empty array would change to an empty string.

---

`x |= y` is essentially shorthand for `x = (x | y)`. The parens are what you were missing in your attempt; they're needed because of `jq` precedence rules.

Comment: added sample json

Comment: Wow! that worked , i knew about '|=' update symbol but last time i used it , it updated all the values with 1 value , maybe i used it wrongly then , anyways thanks!

Answer (score -3):

I'm not familiar with `jq`, but if you just replace every `","` with `,`, it does the trick. It's a hack, so it could break if the input data changes format.

```
$ cat temp.txt 
drop_reasons=["a","b","c"]

$ perl -pe 's/","/,/g' temp.txt
drop_reasons=["a,b,c"]
```

Comment: This will  chnage all the commas in the json

Comment: If they're surrounded by double-quotes, yes. Based on the sample data it would work. If you have a more complete input file you can share I can do better. It'll probably be a Python script, though.